# using cef in MFC dll

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, chromium-embedded

Hi i am trying to develop an MFC dll using cef .Problem am facing is cef's libcef_wrapper_dll is complied in (MT) flag(cant complie in other flags as most of the code doesnt complie with other flags).But my dll is complied using (MD).
I am facing following errors.

```
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8value_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??0?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gptr(void)const " (?gptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setg(char *,char *,char *)" (?setg@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD0@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::eback(void)const " (?eback@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Pninc(void)" (?_Pninc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(v8context_ctocpp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbase(void)const " (?pbase@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::epptr(void)const " (?epptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pptr(void)const " (?pptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gbump(int)" (?gbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::egptr(void)const " (?egptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbump(int)" (?pbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in libcef_dll_wrapper.lib(cef_logging.obj)
1>mfcs100.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::_Facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?_Facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encoded_null already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __malloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: ___CppXcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>     Creating library .\..\bin\Release\Margin Utilisation.lib and object .\..\bin\Release\Margin Utilisation.exp
1>Margin Utilisation.exp : warning LNK4070: /OUT:Margin Utilisation.dll directive in .EXP differs from output filename './../bin/Release/nest_rms_margin_utilisation.nap'; ignoring directive
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering to the

> "C4275: non dll-interface class 'stdext::exception' used as base for dll-interface class 'std::bad_typeid'"

error comment when compiling with MD flag.
You just need to add

```
-D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1
```

to the compilation command line under `Configuration Properties/C/C++/Command Line/Additional Options`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile `libcef_dll_wrapper.lib` with the `MD` flags, The `CefSharp` project uses a version compiled using `MD`. It's relatively easy to recompile, all you need is `cmake`, download the binary from `cefbuilds.com`, generate the `VS` project files, modify them to use `MultiThreaded`, then recompile. Depending on what version you require you can download a `Nuget` package that `CefSharp` uses and extract a pre-compiled version.

From https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.sdk/ you can click the `Download` link, then extract the `Nupkg` file (it's just a `zip`). A new version based on the `2526` branch will be released early next year.

Comment: libcef_dll_wrapper.lib doesnt complie in MD flag

Comment: libcef_dll_wrapper.lib doesnt complie in MD flag.It shows following error(many error of same kind) 

warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'stdext::exception' used as base for dll-interface class 'std::bad_typeid'

Comment: If you use a supported version of Visual studio it will. Asserting that it doesn't repetitively just because you haven't got it compiling successfully yet isn't helpful! Good luck